# how can I set image background for linearlyout?

Tags: android, background

I want to set Image background for linearlyout in android ? can i ? if yes. how ?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set the background attribute of your layout to some drawable for instance :

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/background">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that you should do some research on the site before posting basic questions like that, there are plenty of answers already, and it would save you time instead of waiting for an answer...

Answer (score 0):

simply put, at the top where your linear layout is you can fill in the extra code in this block:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/yourpicture" >
```

also, you can right-click on the black background and select Other Properties>All By Name>Background then select the folder it is in, then the picture/color.